# Importing into SQL from Excel 97-2003

Tags: sql, excel, sqlcmd

I am trying to import the only file format provided by an off the shelf application which uses Excel 97-2003 to export. All fields are stored as text, including the UPC code. The size of the file is an average of over 12 k lines (sample below). Can this be done using `cmdshell` and `sqlcmd`?

[image]

Comment: you didn't say what you're importing it _to_. separately, if you can use some version of Excel to take that document and create a .csv, you will have much more flexibility in porting the data to another system.

Comment: Importing into a new table in SQL in an existing database. In this case the import will go into a table called dbo.NewItems. It should use the imported column headers and as shown in the example all is a varchar.

Comment: Ah, yes, I already know that you can use the SQL import feature, but the common user in this case does not need to get into SQL Server Manager, hence the need for a simple solution. I've done the Excel scripting and it takes to long as does any .Net solution. SQL SMS only takes about 1 minute and that is acceptable to end user. I'm trying to work with end user ability to converting to csv or other format increases ability to make error.